# is any way to know name of indexing which mysql is using when I submit a query?

Tags: mysql, indexing

if I want to know if mysql is using the indexing I can use this SQL to check how many rows scanned for the SQL by checking the ***rows column*** returned:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM table_name1 WHERE `length` = 71;
```

but I wonder if anyway directly show me which indexing mysql is using for the progress. I think it will be more better system  tell me the indexing name.

Take an example:

```
CREATE TABLE `tb1` (
`id` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`num` int(11) NOT NULL,
`length` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `length` (`length`) USING BTREE,
KEY `num_length` (`num`,`length`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The query create a table named "tb1" and create an index for "length" and an index for "length" and "num";

I want to know if the 'length' index works properly.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE `length` = 71
```

;[image]

the result seems only show me 1666 rows scanned but didn;t tell me which index mysql used for the query.

what I want to know is how to get the index name which mysql is using when running a query.

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` tells you which indexes it uses. That's the **only** way.  It's unclear what you're trying to achieve and what kind of optimization you're after. Expand your question and explain the **actual problem** you're having.

Comment: @mjh thank you . I expanded the question and add a example.maybe it seems more clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EXPLAIN` says `key = length`.  So that is *probably* the index being used.  I say *probably* because the query might actually work differently than the `EXPLAIN`.

Something else is puzzling: `AUTO_INCREMENT=2` implies that you have very few rows in the table.  Yet `Rows=1666` implies there are many rows.  Which is correct?

If there are only two rows, it is unlikely to use any index; a table scan is likely to be faster.

In MariaDB 10.0 (and newer versions of MySQL?), there is a way for `EXPLAINing` a *running* query.  However, this query probably runs too fast to let you do that.  Also, the slowlog will have the explain -- use `long_query_time=0`.

As for knowing "when you submit the query", there is no way.  You can only get a very likely answer by first doing `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check indexes like this:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM mytable FROM mydb;
SHOW INDEX FROM mydb.mytable;
```

Comment: thank you.I think it will show all index from the table.but I just want to know which indexes mysql is using when processing